# How to fix this complex CSS grid of photos based on 4 columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

I designed this *1-4 / 4-1 / 1* grid and tried to implemented it with a full CSS grid solution based on 4 columns:

[image: designed grid]

As you can see on the snippet below, it is almost there, except that the 4th and 5th as well as 8th and 9th photos needs to be under other small images. I tried to play with a grid-template-rows but it gets very tricky and quickly messy.
The grid pattern would repeat from the 12th element.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 56px 40px;
  margin: 40px;
}

.photo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* 1st photo = 2 columns, 2 first rows */
.photo:nth-of-type(11n+1) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}


/* 2nd photo and other small ones */
.photo:nth-of-type(11n+1) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

/* 11th photo = 2 columns */
.photo:nth-of-type(11n+10) {
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
}

/* 11th photo = 4 columns */
.photo:nth-of-type(11n) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your code like below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.photo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.photo:nth-child(11n + 1){
  grid-area:span 2/span 2;
}
.photo:nth-child(11n + 10) {
  grid-area:3/3/span 2/span 2
}
.photo:nth-child(11n + 11){
  grid-column:span 4;
  margin-top:10px;
}

.photo:nth-child(11n + 1),
.photo:nth-child(11n + 4),
.photo:nth-child(11n + 5){
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very cool, thanks Temani! The only thing is that the grid-row-gap is applied to each photo and not each set of 5 photos, if you see what I mean. Visually it helps the eye to have more space after pattern each block I feel.

Comment: @flks check the update, you can play with margin to increase the gap

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your css. You can now also have n*11 Images and it will work.
In the codepen you see the code working with 22 Images: https://codepen.io/yourbraineatsyou/pen/xxroWWg

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 56px 40px;
  margin: 40px;
}

.photo img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* 1st photo = 2 columns, 2 first rows */
.photo:nth-of-type(11n+1) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

/* 9th photo = 2 columns, last rows */
.photo:nth-of-type(11n+8) {
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

/* 11th photo = 4 columns */
.photo:nth-of-type(11n) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x533" width="800" height="533" alt="Photo">
  </div>
</div>
```